# Getting Selected Row data from jQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have Try to extract raw data from selected row in jquery datatable. I am using 1.10.7 version.here is my simple code

```
 var table = $('#Searchtbl').DataTable({
                "columns": [
                            { "data": "poNumber" },
                            { "data": "relnumber" },
                            { "data": "recNumber" },
                            { "data": "vendorName"},

                ],
            });



            $('#Searchtbl tbody').on('dblclick', 'tr', function () {
                console.log(table.row(this).data());
                //$('#searchModel').modal('hide');
            });
```

but once console get print it saying undefined.Can any one say what i am doing wrong here,

Answer (score 4):

Finally i fixed this with this way.Reson is the new version of Datatable library no longer working **table.row( this ).data()** this way

```
    var table = $('#Searchtbl').DataTable({
    });


    $('#Searchtbl tbody').on('dblclick', 'tr', function () {
        var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function () {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();

        alert("Your data is: " + $.trim(tableData[0]) + " , " + $.trim(tableData[1]) + " , " + $.trim(tableData[2])+ " , " + $.trim(tableData[3])+ " , " + $.trim(tableData[4]));

    });
```

Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

You need this one ??

```
 $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
     console.log( table.row( this ).data() );
 } );
```

[Detail](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data())

Comment: yes.the table data Dynamically generate by  Ajax Request

Answer (score 0):

Get the data onclick

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    console.log( table.row( this ).data() );
} );
```

[All the Details](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data())

Comment: I want on extract row data when double click on it.i have found answer for it.Thanks